# JS calculation at document level inside a PDF

Tags: javascript, pdf, acrobat

I work on a basic pdf order form with 3 cells where I need calculation.

If it was for only few fiels, I'm used to use the following in [Calculate]

```
var price = this.getField("price");
var qty = this.getField("Qty");

event.target.value = price.value * qty.value;
```

All my fields get the following name structure:

```
[price_1] [Qty_1] [subTot_1]
[price_2] [Qty_2] [subTot_2]
[price_3] [Qty_3] [subTot_3]
...
```

Now, what could be the function at document level that will take in consideration all the occurrence of price Qty and subTot fields, and will update my subTot fields when a user change on a Qty field ?
I've play arround with for loop and so on but not able to target what I want.

Thanks for any advices!

Comment: Shall the user be able to enter the price, or should that be a (maintainable) fixed value?

Answer (score 0):

User just have to update quantity. Prices are fixed.